# What is faster? modulo an int, or divide int by MAX_INT to get a float then multiply by desired modulus value and cast back to int?

Tags: c++, performance

What is faster:

```
random() % 100;
```

or

```
static_cast<int>((random() / 4294967296) * 100);
```

I don't really know how to benchmark properly, and what appears faster on my computer may not work out the same on others, that's why I humbly submit this question to the wise folk on Stackoverflow

Comment: Get current timestamp. Run version 1 1000000 times in a loop. Get current timestamp. Subtract. Repeat for version 2. Compare. Then release that this will probably be highly compiler-, CPU- and OS-dependent and that unless it's happening in a tight loop, it won't even matter and that readability trumps speed in almost all cases.

Comment: What type is the return value of `random()`? If it's an integral type...

Comment: random() returns int, yes.

Comment: ...Then the second snippet will always return 0. BTW, consider a modern alternative https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: Dividing a value of type `int` by `MAX_INT` does not give a `float`.   Also, `4294967296` is unlikely to be equivalent to `MAX_INT` on any architecture.  In any event - apart from the call of `random()` - I'd expect the first to be faster than the second, since modulo typically is (approximately) comparable in speed to a division.     Comparing performance is a bit pointless though, since the two approaches give different results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generating random numbers can be either done with [`rand()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) or [`std::mt19997`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine). The latter is the prefered one, I still benchmarked for both cases. (Visual Studio 2017 Community x64). I use a dummy variable so the compiler can't ignore the random generation statements. `rand()` returns an `int` and `std::mt19937` returns an `std::uint32_t`. To reduce the number of casts I therefore use 2 dummy variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

namespace util {
    constexpr std::size_t loop{ 10'000'000u };
    std::mt19937 engine{ std::random_device{}() };
    int rand_dummy{ 0 };
    std::uint32_t mt19937_dummy{ 0u };
}

void rand_mod() {
    for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < util::loop; ++i) {
        util::rand_dummy = (rand() % 100);
    }
}
void rand_div() {
    for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < util::loop; ++i) {
        util::rand_dummy = static_cast<int>(static_cast<double>(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 100);
    }
}

void mt19937_mod() {
    for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < util::loop; ++i) {
        util::mt19937_dummy = (util::engine() % 100u);
    }
}
void mt19937_div() {
    for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < util::loop; ++i) {
        util::mt19937_dummy = static_cast<std::uint32_t>(static_cast<double>(util::engine()) / std::numeric_limits<std::uint32_t>::max() * 100u);
    }
}

void benchmark(void(*f)(void), const std::string& name) {
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    f();
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << name << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count() / 1e6 << "ms\n";
}

int main() {
    srand(std::random_device{}());

    benchmark(rand_mod,    "rand()       | mod: ");
    benchmark(rand_div,    "rand()       | div: ");
    std::cout << "---------------------------\n";
    benchmark(mt19937_mod, "std::mt19937 | mod: ");
    benchmark(mt19937_div, "std::mt19937 | div: ");

    return util::rand_dummy + util::mt19937_dummy;
}
```

optimizations disabled (/Od):

```
rand()       | mod: 956.128ms
rand()       | div: 796.235ms
---------------------------
std::mt19937 | mod: 437.885ms
std::mt19937 | div: 584.477ms
```

full optimizations (/Ox):

```
rand()       | mod: 276.092ms
rand()       | div: 262.224ms
---------------------------
std::mt19937 | mod: 61.4312ms
std::mt19937 | div: 103.38ms
```

---

- `std::mt19937` is in both cases faster
- for `std::mt19937` **modulus wins over division**
- for `rand()` **division wins over modulus**

So it depends on which one you use. Since `std::mt19937` is superior to `rand()` the answer should be: modulus is faster than division.

[> why `rand()` is considered harmful >](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

---

Note you also shouldn't do:

```
engine() % 100;
```

Instead, use `std::uniform_int_distribiution(0, 99)(engine);`

[`engine` is a `std::mt19937`]